# Differentiating $\int_{0}^{\tan(x)} \sin(t^2) \, dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My attempt:

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\tan(x)} \sin(t^2) \, dt$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)= \sec^2(x)\sin(\tan(x)) \, $$

I don't know if this is correct. I have a test tomorrow and I have nowhere else to check. Thanks.

Comment: That would be right if it was $\int \sin(t)\,dt$...

Comment: Pedantic comment: "Derive" does not mean "take the derivative of". The proper word is "differentiate". I corrected the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer should be $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)= \sec^2(x)\sin(\tan^2(x)) \, $$

The result is obtained by using Leibnitz Rule. For more info on how this rule works, you can check [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)